# Change output background color

Tags: output, turbo-c

How do I change output background color of turboc from black to white.

I need to print the output screen, but printing the whole screen will waste too much ink.

Comment: @dippas that just change's editor's background color and not the output screen's.

Answer (score 2):

you could have easily googled this,still

follow these steps:-

1) go to options menu

 
2) then under environment sub-menu.

3) select the colors option

4)select output screen option and change color.

checkout this link:- http://jnucode.blogspot.in/2011/06/how-to-change-turbo-c-compilers-editor.html